# Vertical table scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Anybody know how to do vertical body scrolling, if table looks like this:

```css
.scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="scroll">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Head 1</th>
            <th colspan="2">Head 2</th>
            <th colspan="3">Head 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
            <th>Head 6</th>
            <th>Head 7</th>
            <th>Head 8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I found many solutions and jQuery plugins, but all of them for linear table header or not working one of browsers(Firefox, Chrome, IE).

Comment: It is already scrolling in vertical. What exactly you want?

Comment: I want only table body scrolling, without title.

Comment: You mean, you want the header part to be still and just the body to be scrolling in case the table is too long!!!

Comment: I want to like this http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/crspu/555/

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: [jQuery Plugin for Fixed Header Tables](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/):

```js
$(function () {
  $("table").fixedHeaderTable({
    footer: true,
    cloneHeadToFoot: true,
    fixedColumn: false,
    height: 100
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.fixedheadertable.com/js/jquery.fixedheadertable.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Head 1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Head 2</th>
      <th colspan="3">Head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 4</th>
      <th>Head 5</th>
      <th>Head 6</th>
      <th>Head 7</th>
      <th>Head 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```